# Error al Sincronizar el gradle en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, bootstrap, gradle

Bueno mi problema que tengo actualmente es que acabo de importar boostrap en mi aplicación de Android, a mi parecer la he importado de manera correcta pero me ha salido este error, el cual no he podido resolver aún.

El error que me sale es el siguiente: No such property: GROUP for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

Aquí esta el Código de build.gradle (Module app) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "onbus.garay.david.onbus"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    }
```

Aquí esta el código de build.gradle (Module OnBus) :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Aquí esta el código de Boostrap.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: 'push.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = 1.0
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
}
```

Comment: ¿Que error te aparece?

Comment: @Error404 ya la modifique, perdón se me había olvidado poner cual error me salia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para solucionar el problema:

> property: GROUP for class:
>   org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

Elimima la referencia :

```
apply from: 'push.gradle'
```

Y sincroniza nuevamente.

No se necesita Maven para tu proyecto.